# Como gerar um gráfico de temperaturas x tempo de dados colhidos por um arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, matplotlib

Boa tarde pessoal, eu estou tentando usar um programa em python para ler sete valores de temperaturas através de da porta serial com o arduino, até agora o programa que eu fiz coleta os dados, salva em um arquivo de texto, e quando eu interrompo a execução ele salva o arquivo de texto e imprime o gráfico na tela, mas eu gostaria de gerar o gráfico ao longo do tempo, não só no fim da execução do programa, gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer isso, eu procurei um estudar sobre o matplotlib, mas eu não consegui encontrar o que eu procurava.
Bom, eu estou deixando aqui na pergunta o que eu escrevi até agora, e uma imagem do gráfico q eu gerei.

```
####importando as bibliotecas necessarias###
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
try:
    porta = str("/dev/ttyACM" + input('Digite o numero da porta em que o arduino está conectado: '))
    nome = str(input('Nome do arquivo que será salvo: ') + '.csv')
    i = 0
    velocidade = 9600
    conexao = serial.Serial(porta, velocidade) #aqui inicia a comunicação serial com o arduino
    with open(nome, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as salvo:
        conexao.write(str.encode('false'))# os dados são armazenados num arquivo de texto
        while True:
            i += 1 #aqui os dados que o arduino envia são lidos até parar a execução do programa
            horario = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            dados = str(conexao.readline())[2:-5]
            if 'Hora' in dados: #a primeira linha que o programa deve ler é a do titulo
                print(dados[-25:])
                salvo.write(dados + '\n')
            if i > 2: #aqui o programa pula as duas primeiras linhas que as vezes o arduino manda com a formatação zoada
                print(horario + ',' + dados)
                salvo.write(horario + ',' + dados + '\n')
except FileNotFoundError: #caso a porta esteja errada
    print('Porta não encontrada!')
except KeyboardInterrupt: #quando o programa é encerrado e o grafico aparece
    data = pd.read_csv(nome)
    #essa parte usa o Pandas para converter o arquivo de texto gerado nas listas que formam o gráfico
    hora = data.iloc[:, 0]
    t1 = data.iloc[:, 1]
    t2 = data.iloc[:, 2]
    t3 = data.iloc[:, 3]
    t4 = data.iloc[:, 4]
    t5 = data.iloc[:, 5]
    t6 = data.iloc[:, 6]
    t7 = data.iloc[:, 7]

    #Essa parte imprime o gráfico na tela
    plt.plot(hora, t1)
    plt.plot(hora, t2)
    plt.plot(hora, t3)
    plt.plot(hora, t4)
    plt.plot(hora, t5)
    plt.plot(hora, t6)
    plt.plot(hora, t7)
    plt.show()
    print('Programa encerrado')
```

[image: grafico]

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar isso dentro do while true, acredito que assim vai gerar o gráfico a medida que recebe os dados

```
data = pd.read_csv(nome)
#essa parte usa o Pandas para converter o arquivo de texto gerado nas listas que formam o gráfico
hora = data.iloc[:, 0]
t1 = data.iloc[:, 1]
t2 = data.iloc[:, 2]
t3 = data.iloc[:, 3]
t4 = data.iloc[:, 4]
t5 = data.iloc[:, 5]
t6 = data.iloc[:, 6]
t7 = data.iloc[:, 7]

#Essa parte imprime o gráfico na tela
plt.plot(hora, t1)
plt.plot(hora, t2)
plt.plot(hora, t3)
plt.plot(hora, t4)
plt.plot(hora, t5)
plt.plot(hora, t6)
plt.plot(hora, t7)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -2):

Procure por FuncAnimation do matplotlib.
Ele permite tanto criar este tipo de gráfico que queres, como reescalar o gráfico conforme a necessidade. Um exemplo que você pode adaptar é o código do MHS Amortecido dado no próprio site de documentação do matplotlib.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animate_decay.html